# Как мне добавить в объект employee age и salary с помощью деструктуризации не изменяя изначальный объект?

Tags: javascript

```
const employee = {
  name: 'Vitalii',
  surname: 'Klichko'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для этого существует [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_%D0%B2_%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0) оператор

```js
const stats = {
  age: 20,
  salary: 2000000,
};

const employee = {
  name: 'Vitalii',
  surname: 'Klichko',
  ...stats,
};

console.log(employee)
```